# How to fetch products from Database using codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing а website for online shopping using CodeIgniter framework.

I am able to fetch a category, and when I click on a category id it will redirect to another page where I want to display all the data from the database related to that category.

How can I fetch data from database using CodeIgniter framework?

Comment: Show us what you tired so far

Comment: `select stuff from table where something = something`

Comment: I'd highly recommend following the [CodeIgniter tutorial](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html) if you've never used a PHP MVC framework before - and even then.

Answer (score 0):

### To fetch data form database in `codeigniter`

## 1. Controllers query

```
public function getdata()
{
   $this->load->model('insert_model');                 
   $data['result'] = $this->my_model->fetch_data($id);

   echo "<pre>";
   preint_r($data['result']); // database return value from model 
}
```

## 2. Models query

```
function fetch_data($id=null)
{
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('mytbl');            // mytbl is database table name
   $this->db->where('id',$id);
   $query = $this->db->get();
   $result = $query->result_array();    // this query fetch result in array     form
   if(!empty($result))
   {
      return $result ;
   }
}
```

## Another way to fetch data from database

```
$query = $this->db->query("select * from mytbl"); 

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   foreach ($query->result() as $row)
   {
      echo $row->title;
      echo $row->name;
      echo $row->body;
   }
}
```